# .Net Core change Swashbuckle favicon from custom html

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I am trying to customize the favicon for our .net core api and set it to an image within our project structure.  I am not able to get it to load though and have tried a few things that have not worked.  This is how I am using my custom html for Swashbuckle in Startup.cs (Located in a folder called Swagger):

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.IndexStream = () => GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly
                    .GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Swagger.index.html");
            });
```

**Attempt #1:**

Add the use of StaticFiles to my Startup.cs Configure method like so:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Then I placed the the logo.png (Set as Copy Always) inside the wwwroot folder under an Images folder and tried to reference it in the html like this. (I have also tried to reference it from an Images folder in the same directory as the html).

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="~/Images/logo.png" />
```

No dice and there is now no favicon in the tab.

**Attempt #2.**

Overwrite the favicon via Javascript inside the html file.

```
var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');
link.type = 'image/png';
link.rel = 'icon';
link.href = '~/Images/logo.png';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

No dice, the swagger favicon still exists.

Has anybody successfully been able to replace the favicon using Swashbuckle?

The version of Swashbuckle I am using is `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 2.4.0`

This is the html file I am using based on the default file from here https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/index.html

```
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>%(DocumentTitle)</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Source+Code+Pro:300,600|Titillium+Web:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./swagger-ui.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="~/Images/logo.png" />
    <style>
        html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            background: #fafafa;
        }
        hgroup.main {
            display: none;
        }
        .swagger-ui .topbar {
            background-color: #00CCCC;
        }
    </style>
    %(HeadContent)
</head>

<body>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0">
        <defs>
            <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="unlocked">
                <path d="M15.8 8H14V5.6C14 2.703 12.665 1 10 1 7.334 1 6 2.703 6 5.6V6h2v-.801C8 3.754 8.797 3 10 3c1.203 0 2 .754 2 2.199V8H4c-.553 0-1 .646-1 1.199V17c0 .549.428 1.139.951 1.307l1.197.387C5.672 18.861 6.55 19 7.1 19h5.8c.549 0 1.428-.139 1.951-.307l1.196-.387c.524-.167.953-.757.953-1.306V9.199C17 8.646 16.352 8 15.8 8z"></path>
            </symbol>

            <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="locked">
                <path d="M15.8 8H14V5.6C14 2.703 12.665 1 10 1 7.334 1 6 2.703 6 5.6V8H4c-.553 0-1 .646-1 1.199V17c0 .549.428 1.139.951 1.307l1.197.387C5.672 18.861 6.55 19 7.1 19h5.8c.549 0 1.428-.139 1.951-.307l1.196-.387c.524-.167.953-.757.953-1.306V9.199C17 8.646 16.352 8 15.8 8zM12 8H8V5.199C8 3.754 8.797 3 10 3c1.203 0 2 .754 2 2.199V8z" />
            </symbol>

            <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="close">
                <path d="M14.348 14.849c-.469.469-1.229.469-1.697 0L10 11.819l-2.651 3.029c-.469.469-1.229.469-1.697 0-.469-.469-.469-1.229 0-1.697l2.758-3.15-2.759-3.152c-.469-.469-.469-1.228 0-1.697.469-.469 1.228-.469 1.697 0L10 8.183l2.651-3.031c.469-.469 1.228-.469 1.697 0 .469.469.469 1.229 0 1.697l-2.758 3.152 2.758 3.15c.469.469.469 1.229 0 1.698z" />
            </symbol>

            <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="large-arrow">
                <path d="M13.25 10L6.109 2.58c-.268-.27-.268-.707 0-.979.268-.27.701-.27.969 0l7.83 7.908c.268.271.268.709 0 .979l-7.83 7.908c-.268.271-.701.27-.969 0-.268-.269-.268-.707 0-.979L13.25 10z" />
            </symbol>

            <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="large-arrow-down">
                <path d="M17.418 6.109c.272-.268.709-.268.979 0s.271.701 0 .969l-7.908 7.83c-.27.268-.707.268-.979 0l-7.908-7.83c-.27-.268-.27-.701 0-.969.271-.268.709-.268.979 0L10 13.25l7.418-7.141z" />
            </symbol>


            <symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="jump-to">
                <path d="M19 7v4H5.83l3.58-3.59L8 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L5.83 13H21V7z" />
            </symbol>

            <symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="expand">
                <path d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z" />
            </symbol>

        </defs>
    </svg>

    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>

    <!-- Workaround for https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/1371 -->
    <script>
        if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1) {
            console.log("Removing native Edge fetch in favor of swagger-ui's polyfill")
            window.fetch = undefined;
        }
    </script>

    <script src="./swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="./swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var configObject = JSON.parse('%(ConfigObject)');
            var oauthConfigObject = JSON.parse('%(OAuthConfigObject)');

            // Apply mandatory parameters
            configObject.dom_id = "#swagger-ui";
            configObject.presets = [SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis, SwaggerUIStandalonePreset];
            configObject.layout = "StandaloneLayout";

            // If oauth2RedirectUrl isn't specified, use the built-in default
            if (!configObject.hasOwnProperty("oauth2RedirectUrl"))
                configObject.oauth2RedirectUrl = window.location.href.replace("index.html", "oauth2-redirect.html");

            // Build a system
            const ui = SwaggerUIBundle(configObject);

            // Apply OAuth config
            ui.initOAuth(oauthConfigObject);

            //Custom scripting
            document.getElementsByClassName("link")[0].innerHTML = "Application Name";
            document.getElementsByClassName("link")[0].removeAttribute("href");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your Attempt #1 should have worked... but the fact that you get no favicon in the tab,  tells me your image is not deploying correctly or the path you are using is not the right one. Can you confirm you can see the image on that path?

Comment: @HelderSepu I am running locally with the Project build and not IIS, should I be looking for the image in the build output folder instead?

Comment: I can see the file output under bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/Images/logo.png as well as bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/wwwroot/Images/logo.png

Comment: Do you have your project on GitHub? Can you share a link? If not can you create a minimal project there and share a link

Comment: Yup, will do and get back to you with the Repo url

Comment: @HelderSepu This is the url for the minimal repo for getting it running with swashbuckle.  I have commented out the code for both of my attempts in the Swagger/index.html file.  https://github.com/ShawnCholeva/Swashbuckle

Comment: Sent you a PR on github, changing the favicon work! The problem is not swashbuckle but your deployment or the path you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. However, I utilized the Index located here:

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/tree/master/test/WebSites/CustomUIIndex/Swagger

From here, I was able to change the logo with the following:

```
<div id="header">
    <section class="swagger-ui swagger-container" data-reactroot="">
        <div class="topbar">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="topbar-wrapper">
                    <a class="link">
                        <img alt="Swagger UI" src="/Swagger/UI/Logo.jpg" />
                        <span style="font-size:medium; color:black;text-wrap:none;text-align:right" >YourTitle</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`, you can do this:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
  options.HeadContent = "<link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/png\" href=\"https://site/favicon.ico\" sizes=\"16x16\"
```

It will override the default favicon provided earlier in the html.

You may need to provide all/more sizes.

Should work fine with a local `wwwroot` favicon.